# Add two numbers in Jquery getting abnormal output

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

In the below code im going to add two number but there not add just shows me two numbers respectively.

```
 var gross = $('#txtgross').val();// 226800.00
 tax = ((vat) + (nbt)); // vat is 34020.00 and nbt is 4536.00

 net = ((gross) + tax.toFixed(2)); // 226800.00 38556.00 <-- in here not calculated but it just shows the Gross & Total Tax (nbt + vat) amounts respectively
```

Comment: You're concatenating strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `parseInt` to **add numbers** as shown :

```
var tax = (parseInt(vat) + parseInt(nbt));
```

or Use `parseFloat` as shown :

```
var tax = (parseFloat(vat) + parseFloat(nbt));
```

The problem in your case is that the numbers are also considered as strings and when you are adding them then the strings are just concatenating.

Comment: this is double filed